# Using Python to create specific folder within multiple folders

Tags: python, directory, subdirectory

I have a directory containing 450 folders, all unique names. Inside this folder I need to create a sub-folder called Metadata, so it looks like the following:
Folder1/Metadata
Folder2/Metadata
Folder3/Metadata

Is there a way using Python to create this example?

Comment: You can create a folder with `os.makedir(path)`. See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkdir) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

The functions you are looking for are all in the [os module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#module-os):

```
import os
for item in os.listdir('.'):
    if os.path.isdir(item):
        newdir = os.path.join(item, 'Metadata')
        if not os.path.exists(newdir):
            os.makedirs(newdir)
```

Comment: I guess directories are not recursive as per the details, so **mkdir** should also work.